# html + rails question

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

Can I add ruby/ rails code inside an html page. My requirement is, get a partial to display in my html page

Is this possible and if yes please show me how.

My current code is:

### index.html:

```
<%= render :partial => <partial>%>
```

So what I'm trying to do here is have the partial rendered to my html page.

I'm using rails 3 on ubuntu.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
sameera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render partial like this:

```
<%= render :partial => 'name_of_partial', :locals => { :some_variable_to_pass_to_partial => "abcd" } %>
```

Here is some good information about [layouts and views in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

Comment: Hi Zabba thanks for the reply, r u sure you can do this in a pure html page. coz I'm having a pure help page and I want to call rails partial. for me its just printing '<%= render :partial => 'test'%> ' as a string thanks

Comment: What do you mean "pure HTML page" ? Do you mean it is "static" HTML ? Is the file-extension of the file ending in `.erb`? (this is required - it won't work if the file-extension is `.html`.)

Comment: hi zabba. yes I mean static html (.html) . thanks for the help cheers sameeta

Comment: Well, static HTML is meant to be static; what is the goal you are trying to accomplish? Maybe you're thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: The point of an index.html.erb file is that it's parsed to turn Ruby code into html. Without the .erb tag, it's entirely html as far as the browser/server is concerned.